# Como adicionar funções em programas em C?

Tags: c, funções

Preciso saber como introduzir funções em qualquer programa. Se alguém puder me dar um exemplo nesse programa aqui, talvez eu consiga aplicar em outros também. Preciso entender a lógica de como aplicar as funções.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int n, some, divisor;

  printf("Digite um numero inteiro positivo: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  soma = 0;

  for (divisor = 1; divisor < n; divisor++){
    if ( n % divisor == 0 )
      soma = soma = + divisor;
  }

  if ( n == soma )
    printf("O numero %d e perfeito \n", n);
  else
    printf("o numero %d nao e perfeito \n", n);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você quer fazer a soma através de uma função é isso ? Não ficou muito claro o que está à procura.

Comment: A que funções se refere? Algo como `int soma(int x, int y){ return x+y; }` ?

Comment: Permita-me refrasear. Quais funções você quer construir ? Que lógica é suposto ser feita por que funções ? Comece por clarificar esses pontos primeiro.

Comment: Dica: seu programa já declara uma função (`main`) e usa outras duas (`printf` e `scanf`).

Comment: Acredito que uma pesquisa no Google resolva em 1 minuto

Answer (score 1):

Penso que o teu objectivo é este:

```
int main(){
   int n;
   printf("Digite um numero inteiro positivo: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   // AQUI SE CHAMA A FUNCAO E MANDAM OS PARAMETROS NECESSARIOS NESTE CASO É 
   //SÓ UMA VARIAVEL   
   if(CheckIfPerfect(n)){
      printf("O numero %d e perfeito \n". n);
   }else{
      printf("O numero %d nao e perfeito \n",n);

   }

int CheckIfPerfect(int n){
   int soma = 0;
   int divisor;

   for(divisor = 1;divisor<n; divisor++){
      if(n % divisor == 0){
         soma+=divisor;
      }
   }
   if(n == soma){
      //DEVOLVE 0 EQUIVALE A TRUE  
      return 0;
   }else{
      //DEVOLVE 1,2,3.... EQUIVALE A false  
      return 1;
   }

}
```

Comment: Parece que o código atende ao que foi pedido, mas seria legal clicar em [edit] e explicar o que foi feito no código, para que ele entenda as características de uma função em C, valorizando o ensinamento para o autor da pergunta e futuros visitantes

Comment: Concordo com o que o @Bacco disse. Mas para além disso existem diversos erros com o seu código, por favor considere uma correção.

Answer (score 0):

A partir do seu programa, dá pra fazer uma função separada e fora da main, que faça esse cálculo. O benefício das funções, é que você pode chamá-las a partir de qualquer lugar do programa e muitas vezes irá economizar linhas. Por exemplo, se por algum motivo você quisesse efetuar o mesmo cálculo no final da main, você teria que repetir todo o for. Se fizer uma função que faça esse cálculo, basta chamá-la.

O protótipo de uma função é a seguinte:

```
<tipo> <nome_da_função>(<parâmetros>)
{
    código;
    ...;
}
```

O tipo da função define o tipo que irá ser retornado pela função. Na função pra efetuar o seu cálculo, o resultado disso, ou seja, a  variável `soma`, será um número inteiro, logo o valor retornado será um número inteiro, então o tipo é o `int`.

O nome da função vale as mesmas regras pra nomear uma variável, nada de novo por aqui.

O parâmetro de uma função é o que você precisa pra efetuar o seu cálculo ou o que você precisa que seja passado pra sua função pra fazer qualquer coisa dentro dela. Pra você fazer o seu `for` você precisa do elemento que o usuário digitou (o `n`), pois ele faz parte do `for`. Logo, ele é um parâmetro para sua função.
 **Obersvação:** Note que os parâmetros são variáveis, e devem ser declaradas como variáveis também.

Até agora, já sabemos o tipo e os parâmetros da função, então já podemos criá-la.

```
int divisor(int elem)
{
    int divisor = 0, soma = 0;

    for (divisor = 1; divisor < elem; divisor++)
        if ( elem % divisor == 0 )
            soma = soma = + divisor;

    return soma;
}
```

Note que o parâmetro não precisa ter, necessariamente, o mesmo nome da varável que irá passar, em outras palavras: o nome da variável dentro da função pode ser diferente da variável que está na main.

Função criada, basta chamar ela na main pra fazer o cálculo necessário.
Resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int divisor(int elem)
{
    int divisor = 0, soma = 0;

    for (divisor = 1; divisor < elem; divisor++)
        if ( elem % divisor == 0 )
            soma = soma = + divisor;

    return soma;
}

int main()
{
    int n, resultado;

    printf("Digite um numero inteiro positivo: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /*A função divisor retornará o resultado do cálculo, logo posso     
      igualá-la a uma variável (Essa variável será igual ao resultado      
      da conta) */
    resultado = divisor(n);

    if (resultado == n)
        printf("O numero %d e perfeito \n", n);
    else
        printf("o numero %d nao e perfeito \n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Caso não tenha entendido algo, pergunte aqui ou procure na internet, tem muito material sobre isso, de resto é só costume, eu também não entendia, mas se você usar/ver muito isso, vai se acostumar e aprender a usar.